# How to display gameobject(prefab folder) as image?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I develop a fishing game.I have in prefab folders a lot of fishes.I go fish , i catch , increase score etc. but i want to display in a corner last fish that i catch.How can i do that? There is my code :

```
if (Sansa == 1) // rechin
     {
         RoosterAnimC.Play("Main|Ridicare_Undita");
         LabelButon.text = "";
         ComponentaButon.interactable = false;
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
         PestePrins = (GameObject)Instantiate(Peste.gameObject, PunctIntrare.transform.position, PunctIntrare.transform.rotation);
         NrPesti.text = (System.Int32.Parse(NrPesti.text) + 1).ToString();
         Score.text = (System.Int32.Parse(Score.text) - 70).ToString();
        // TextNotificare.text = "That’s not a demo. Give me your money!";
         TextNotificare.text = getRandomMessagefromRechin();
         Debug.Log(PestePrins);

         ReplicaPeste.text = "";


         yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

     }
```

PestePrins means CatchedFish in english.I translate because i'm from Romania and i want you to understand my variable names. I instantiate PestePrins as gamobject. If u notice , a few rows down , i Debug.Log(PestePrins) , i dispplay my catched fish . How can i display it in a corner as image ? Or display anywhere for this moment.I don't find anything to help me on internet. I'm newbie by the way. Thanks for helping me,have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd love for this to work, I need the same feature - last time I checked this didn't work though. You can, however use

> AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview to get the preview Texture2D's from your assets, then encode those textures into PNGs and save them out to be used as assets in your game.

-[Source](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/738553/how-to-generate-a-texture2d-of-the-thumbnail-of-a.html)

Because you cannot use AssetPreview in the built game, only in the unity editor, you can take an AssetPreview in the editor, save that image and add to your assets and use it from there.

Once you've done this, it's simply a matter of finding the correct image and setting it on a UI-image with something like

```
myImage = Resources.Load(fishTypeImage) as Sprite;
GameObject.Find("My-Ui-Image").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = myImage;
```

There are of course workarounds... I suppose you could add another camera which you render dispaly in the corner and put the last object you found in a position in front of that camera. With this you can make a sort of dynamic camera where the Object is spinning or whataver. It's a bit messy and I'd love for something like AssetPreview to work in the built version, would be cool!